# In RWBY was Winter abusive?

Tags: rwby

In RWBY Volume 3, Chapter 4: Lessons Learned | Rooster Teeth - YouTube

Winter hits again the first time was in

Watch you see Winter asked Weiss "How have you been?" Weiss was telling her, and Winter for no reason hits her.

Comment: Can you share the relevant clips, rather than the whole video? I’m not sure whether there are copyright issues, but it’s more convenient for people not to have to browse through a long video.

Answer (score 3):

This question is difficult, because regional and cultural differences will tend to impact what one perceives as "Abuse."

However, the situation *does* incline itself to being *interpreted* as abuse simply because of the position of power that Winter occupies within their dynamic: because Winter is *established* as the definite authority figure as the older sister, when she hits Weiss, it has an uncomfortable resemblance, for the audience, to abuse.

Whether it *is* abusive is up for debate, though it probably isn't as abuse is derived around asserting Power while Winter is trying to *teach* Weiss... although hitting her is still wrong.

This is similar to when Killy "revives" Cibo's machine-corpse by *bashing her head against a wall* in the Netflix adaptation of Blame! in the fact that it *looks* like abuse because Killy holds the (literal) power in that relationship (though, to be fair, it was worse in Blame! simply because of Killy's apparent complete and total apathy towards Cibo's fate in that film.)

Answer (score 1):

It was wrong for Winter to hit Weiss, yes, but somehow obviously she's not abusive really. I'm not sure how to prove it other than to point out it's clear Weiss loves Winter, she hates their father who was confirmed to be abusive, and Weiss would live with Winter than stay with her father. Proven by the fact that in volume 5, Weiss was trying to go to Winter after she left her father who practically kidnapped her at the end of Volume 3. But you can see how their father was abusive in this video.

Parent or not, he had no right to hit her, much less hit her scar, on top of the fact he hit her harder than Winter did. Really, Winter treats Weiss better and Weiss loves and looks up to Winter (Which I don't see as the acts of someone being abused) especially since in comparison, Weiss hates her father who did abuse her as stated multiple times in the show. (If only I could find the clip where Weiss said this.) then I prove it was stated.

Answer (score 0):

No. She is very authoritive but she's not abusive. Winter loves Weiss but sometimes Weiss can be disrespectful. Snapping "I Can't!" When Winter was trying to teach her something so Winter had a right to slap her.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! This is a nice first answer but would be better if you added sources. Worth noting that, in my culture at least, someone being difficult doesn't give the other person a right to slap them! Also make sure to register your account!

Comment: It does when the person being difficult is your younger sister who had for a time lived under your roof and had you train them. https://youtu.be/bZAS_rzgCE0

Comment: @Kat In a lot of cultures that still doesn't give you the right to slap them, and it would still be considered abusive. Is there evidence of other characters acting in the same way to actually demonstrate that it's just part of the culture (though one that people/viewers from other cultures would find abusive)?

Comment: Maybe i am mistaking but it did appear to punishment for mouthing off had Winter been her mother not her sister people would've viewed it as "ok" it's the fact it's sister that they're going that's abuse. But Winter appears to be her Gaurdian they're are videos that show Weiss living with Winter not their parents so

Comment: doesn't that give Winter legal rights to Weiss?

Comment: In many countries this would still not give you the right to hit someone. Hitting your kids would be punishable by law as far as I know in Germany for example. You are not allowed to hit *anyone*, no matter what connection you have with them. Only in self-defence, if you are a police officer who is supposed to subdue someone or for example in certain martial arts contests. Could you mention a country/culture where it's viewed as okay for a mother to hit their child if the child is being difficult? (And a tip again: you can notify users in comments by writing an "@" in front of their name.)

Comment: This answer, and the question itself, seem rather opinionated. What may be considered "normal" or "justifiable" in one region might be totally unacceptable in another.

Answer (score 0):

No. If Winter was abusive much like their father was:

Then Weiss would likely be angry at Winter same as she is constantly angry with their father. But Weiss doesn't act like she feels Winter abuses her; she loves Winter and rushed to her when Winter first showed up and also Weiss didn't want Winter to go back to atlas it seemed because she was upset when Winter told her she was leaving. Now no this doesn't make it right for her to just hit Weiss but maybe that was her acting out of anger simply because Weiss being disrespectful. However, it's not Winter's fault entirely it was the way they were raised which means it was mostly the parents fault, and that also means that likely Winter was abused by their father as well.