# In RWBY was Winter abusing Weiss?

Tags: rwby

In RWBY volume 3 Winter hits Weiss twice for no reason, yet Weiss seemed to love Winter and get upset over this but at the same time she hates their father who we know was abusive but Winter seems equally bad. So I am I missing something or is Winter just abusive?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! This question could do with being made easier to read, you can do that by [edit]ing it.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this exact question was [already asked by someone ten hours ago](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185745/in-rwby-was-winter-abusive?rq=1)...

Comment: @F1Krazy I'd vote to dupe it, but the other has no answer

Comment: @Machavity Mod to the rescue!

Comment: @ThiscrispyKat, if you happen to be the same person who posted the previous question, then instead of reposting you should [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/185745/edit) the original. If you're not, then no worries - there's often more than one person wondering the same thing :-)

Comment: There is no other question like this on here?

Comment: I checked! No one else had asked.

Comment: I'm afraid someone already has, and we've linked you the question. I'll see if I can write up an answer on the original question when I get home.

Comment: It's not showing one.